# Google Cloud Build loses ability to authenticate with my private GitHub repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, google-cloud-build

I'm having problems running my cloud build triggers reliably because of what appears to be a credentials timeout.

I have set up my Google Cloud devops project within Google Cloud Build and authenticated the triggers with my private GitHub repository. My private GitHub repository has the Cloud Build GitHub App integration.

My Cloud Build triggers work for a while, running fine whether run automatically or manually.

Then after a few hours I started to get errors in my trigger execution:

```
...
FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com...
```

To try to resolve this I have used the Cloud Build triggers page to disconnect and then re-connect and re-authenticate with my private GitHub repository. The repository management page shows a successful re-authentication, but I still get a "Invalid username or password" error when I run my triggers.

Is there something I'm missing about the way private repository authentication works? Is there another setting I'm missing that auto-refreshes Cloud Build authentication?

Comment: I think this issue is more on git hub issue and was resolved a few hours ago, are you still facing the error?

Comment: I am still facing the issue. I disconnected and reconnected. Do you have a link to the GitHub issue? Maybe there's more I can try.

Comment: Disregard my first comment the issue still ongoing.

Comment: @JohnMichaelGelilio I'm having the same issue and it's 3/2/2021 Is this ongoing or resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is the same to this public tracker issue:

[Unable to fetch repository from Github](https://issuetracker.google.com/172325510)

Google Cloud Engineering Team is working on solving the issue. You can star the public issue tracker feature requests and add comment in the thread that you are also affected to ensure that you will receive the updates about it.